# how to concatenate multiple lines separated by \

Tags: python

I would like to filter lines which start with RUN and are separated by \  e.g.

```
RUN install-repository \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"

RUN ...
```

at the moment I got

```
RUN install-repository \
RUN install-repository \
...
```

with the below code:

```
import urllib2

def run():

    file_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgruening/docker-recipes/master/galaxy-exom-seq/Dockerfile"

    data = urllib2.urlopen(file_url)

    for line in data:
        if line.startswith("RUN"):
            print line.rstrip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't see an answer get accepted for this one, so I'll give it a try.

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re

def run():
    re1 = '^RUN'
    re2 = '^    "--url'
    file_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgruening/docker-recipes/master/galaxy-exom-seq/Dockerfile"
    data = urlopen(file_url)
    for line in data:
        if re.search(re1, line) or re.search(re2, line):
            print(line.rstrip('\\\n'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I think that will get it.

Comment: Thank you. I changed print(line.rstrip('\n')) and re2 = "--url".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> commands = []
>>> a = StringIO.StringIO("RUN aaa\nRUNafas\nRUNaaa\n")
>>> for line in a:
...     if line.startswith("RUN"):
...         commands.append(line.rstrip())
... 
>>> print " \\\n".join(commands)
RUN aaa \ 
RUNafas \
RUNaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of concatenated lines with:

```
lines = []
for line in open('runtest.txt'):
    if s and line.startswith('RUN'):
        lines.append(s)
        s = ''
    s += line.rstrip('\\\n')
```

e.g. with `runtest.txt`:

```
RUN install-repository \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"

RUN install-repository \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"

RUN install-repository \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools" \
    "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"
```

You get:

```
RUN install-repository     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2"     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools"     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"
RUN install-repository     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2"     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools"     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"
RUN install-repository     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o iuc --name gatk2 --panel-section-name GATK2"     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name suite_samtools_0_1_19 --panel-section-name SAMTools"     "--url http://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/ -o devteam --name freebayes --panel-section-name Freebayes"
```